# Programmatically assign python3 class instance attributes

Tags: python-3.x

I may have a few dozen different classes instances with varying attributes that I just need to put patterns/random values into and don't want to have to manually code it all out.  Is there a way to loop thru the attributes in a class instance?

For example:

```
class test_class:
   attr1=0
   attr2=0
   attr3=0
i=test_class()
#How do I do the below in a loop without knowing the attribute names?
i.attr1=1
i.attr2=1
i.attr3=1
```

I know how I can get a list/dict of the attributes, but how do I do it so I can assign values to those attributes?  How do I programmatically loop thru the class instance attributes and assign new values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here... do you really want class attributes vs instance attributes here? Could you give a use case as this currently looks very anti-Pythonic.

Comment: you object *has no instance attributes*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know the attribute names you can just use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr)
If you just want to get a list of all object's attributes you can use [dir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: I dont know the attribute names.  but I see, I can get the list and put the value into setattr

Comment: Don't use `dir`